# Display an attribute from fetched data React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to display some data after using fetch API, I just can't figure out how to do it.

I'm using hooks and my code looks like this:

```js
export default function MedProfilScreen({ route }) {
  //const {id,name,specialite,work}=route.params;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http:......")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(res => {
        setData(
          res.items);
        console.log(res);
      })
      .done();
  });
}
```

Here is a look at the console log of the data:

```js
Array [
  Object {
    "code": "12459552",
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Dr xavier vilan",
    "speciality": "Cardio",
  },
  Object {
    "education": Array [
      Object {
        "date_debut": "2020-02-07",
        "date_end": "2020-02-06",
        "diplome": "asmaa",
        "school": "asmaa",
        "city": "vullez",
      },
      ]}
]
```

Let's assume I use a flat list, How can I display the 'date_end' and the 'School'?

```js
render(){
  return(
   <FlatList 
     data={}
     keyExtractor={item=> item.id.toString()}
     renderItem= {({item})=> <Text> {item.date_end}{item.school} </Text>} />
  )
}
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: It's because when you use `setData` a new render is triggered.  You might want to add to the dependency list for your `useEffect`. i.e. `useEffect(() => {}, [])`

Comment: hi @Johan can you expand  your response more.thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects

Comment: @Johan thank you i did this : setData(res.items) and its good. know i'm trying to display the attributes,any idea?

Comment: You're not passing anything into `data` property in your FlatList though? This needs to have `data` array to display the `item`

Comment: @Jono i know, what should i pass then?

Comment: You should pass your state object that contains the data values (something like `this.state.data`). So it would be something like `data={this.state.data}`